# What does it mean when a female 'displays her wares'?

Tags: meaning

What does it mean when a female 'displays her wares'? I've heard this before and am unsure what it actually means.

Comment: Holy mack ! Someone had to ask?

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a derogatory comment meaning her clothing is too revealing - skirt too short, neckline too low, everything is too tight or sheer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Like in a market, she displays her sexual "offering," revealing parts of her body.